# What are some non Linux-Based operating systems?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, operating-system, bsd

I need to install a VM of an operating systems that is not based on Linux/Unix, Windows or Mac.

I tried to use NetBSD and FreeBSD, but both seem to be too simple, since I need to run applications and write something about the system's characteristics (like, if it's a time sharing, distributed or network system and run some commands on its terminal to see basic system properties).

Is there a good OS, not based in Linux (like BSD) that has a simple installation and it's easy to use (preferably with a "graphics package" and not just terminal, since I need to run applications)?

Feel free to ask for more details and thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: NetBSD and FreeBSD are both based on (well, are) Unix - which would rule them out based on your first sentence. Maybe Minix?

Comment: This list might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_operating_systems

Comment: @user3486184 NetBSD and FreeBSD are both Unix-Like, so they were ruled out.

Comment: @user3486184 Are all Unix and Unix-like systems based on Linux? Plus, does this Minix have a "graphics package"? (I don't know if that's the right word, I'm referring to being able to open applications like Firefox, Games and not just a terminal)?

Comment: If all Unix and Unix-like operating systems are ruled out (including Linux), that narrows your list down significantly. FreeDOS?

Comment: @user3486184 So just BSD, own/original and RTOS should be considered, looking only to the wikipedia article? If so, which one of these do you consider to be the most user-friendly?

Comment: BSD is Unix, which rules that out. Most RTOS operating systems won't have a GUI. @Santiago Nuñez-Corrales suggestion of Haiku is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [Haiku OS](https://www.haiku-os.org), a direct descendent of [BeOS](https://www.wired.com/2015/05/os-almost-made-apple-entirely-different-company/). It has many interesting features:

- A micro-kernel implemented entirely in C++
- Very elegant API design
- A filesystem with a clear metadata structure
- Plenty of opportunities for developers to collaborate and learn

Comment: How difficult it is to install Haiku? I tried but it appears to be somehow difficult.

Comment: It is not difficult to install using any virtual environment capable of mounting an ISO image. I use VirtualBox for that matter. Download the latest Haiku image (Anyboot ISO, https://download.haiku-os.org/nightly-images/x86_64/), attach it as a simulated CD-ROM and boot the VM with a 4 GB virtual drive. Follow the instructions at https://www.haiku-os.org/get-haiku/installation-guide.

Comment: An amendment. Download the 32bit extension for VirtualBox. https://download.haiku-os.org/nightly-images/x86_gcc2_hybrid/